# Is there a way to dynamically update the URL :id parameter in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am looking for a way to dynamically update the :id paramter in my react application using react router dom. I have these codes:

```
import Blog from './pages/Blogpage/Blog'

import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";


 <Route path="/allPosts/page/:id">
      {<Blog/>}
    </Route>
```

This is the link on navigation bar that takes user to the component called Blog.

```
 <li className='topListItem'> 
     <Link className='link' to={`/allPosts/page/${sesssionPageNumber}`}>
      BLOG
      </Link>
    </li>
```

Now, what I want to do is when a user clicks a button, the page address number changes. sessionPageNumber is a useState and I would like the URL which has :id parameter to also change as the useState number increases or decreases.

```
const handleNext = ()=>{
  setPage(page + 1)
}

<MdNavigateNext onClick={handleNext} className='custom-next-prev-icon'/>
```

The problem is that the URL parameter does not change as the useState is updated via the button. The URL :id parameter remains the same which is the default value.

Is there a way I can update the URL :id parameter when the `handleNext` function is called on the button?

Comment: use `useNavigate`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `useNavigate` hook for exactly this. You just need to instantiate the hook at the top of your component, and then you can use it to navigate the user dynamically like so:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Blog(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // ...

  const handleNext = () => {
    navigate(`/allPosts/page/${sesssionPageNumber+1}`);
  }

  // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can issue an imperative navigation action from the current page value.

Based on your route declaration I'll assume you are using `react-router-dom@5`, so you will use the `useHistory` hook to accomplish this. Remember that all route path params are a string type, so you will need to convert `id` to a number if you want to add 1 to it so you don't accidentally apply string concatenation, i.e. `"1" + 1 -> "11"` vs `Number("1") + 1 -> 2`.

Example:

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();
const { id } = useParams();

...

const handleNext = ()=>{
  history.push(`/allPosts/page/${Number(id) + 1}`);
}

...

<MdNavigateNext onClick={handleNext} className='custom-next-prev-icon'/>
```

If on the offhand chance you ***are*** using `react-router-dom@6` then replace the `useHistory` hook with the `useNavigate` hook.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();
const { id } = useParams();

...

const handleNext = ()=>{
  navigate(`/allPosts/page/${Number(id) + 1}`);
}

...

<MdNavigateNext onClick={handleNext} className='custom-next-prev-icon'/>
```

and fix the route

```
<Route path="/allPosts/page/:id" element={<Blog/>} />
```

### Additional note

You very likely don't need to store any `sesssionPageNumber` locally as this is easily derived from the current URL path, i.e. the `id` route path param.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me. You said that I may not need to store the sessionPageNumber locally. What if there is a page reload, will the current page number still be there?

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz Is the "sesssionPageNumber" the `id` path parameter? If so, then no, you can just read the param directly. If not can you explain what it is and how it's used differently from the `id` path parameter?

Comment: Yes, the sessionPageNumber is the value that is passed to the :id path. It is based on number, so as user click next button, we add 1 to it and that signifies the page number. So, if a user is on page 3 for instance and reloads the page, wont that user lose that page and start afresh? Maybe I didnt implement properly but I simply stored the number in browser sessionStorage and retrieve from there. It works now exactly how I want though

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz "if a user is on page 3 for instance and reloads the page, wont that user lose that page and start afresh?" - No, the `id` param would still be 3 when reloading the page. If they navigate to page 4, they would start on page 4, right? Is there something I'm missing of understanding your app's UI/UX?

Comment: Oh, now I understand better. I may simply remove the sessionStorage then. Thank you very much for your help.